# Consuming WebService from Web Service Client

Tags: web-services

I'm trying to consume a web service using Eclipse. I created a Web Service Client from the following wsdl: https://www.esnfs.com.br:8444/enfsws/services/Enfs?wsdl

Using this, I generated 5 classes:

- Enfs.java
- EnfsLocator.java
- EnfsPortType.java
- EnfsPortTypeProxy.java
- EnfsSoap11BindingStub.java

I don't know how to use these classes. How do they work? I need some help using these classes, along with consuming the Web Services.

Comment: We cant access the WSDL as it requires certificate based authentication.

Comment: Hi, sent me your e-mail that I send you the certificate...